# how to implement contains operator in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, operators, plpgsql, contains

How to implement contains operator for strings which returns true if left string contains in right string.

Operator name can be any. I tried @@ and code below but

`select 'A' @@ 'SAS'`

returns false.

How to fix ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.contains(searchFor text, searchIn text)
RETURNS bool

AS $BODY$ BEGIN

RETURN position( searchFor in searchIn)<>0;

END; $BODY$ language plpgsql immutable  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

CREATE OPERATOR public.@@ (
    leftarg = text,
    rightarg = text,
    procedure = public.contains
);
```

Using Postgres 9.1 and above in windows and linux.

```
select contains('A' , 'SAS' )
```

returns true as expected.

**Update**

I tried in 9.1 code from answer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.contains(searchFor text, searchIn text)
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
AS $BODY$
SELECT position( searchFor in searchIn )<>0;
$BODY$;


CREATE OPERATOR public.<@ (
    leftarg = text,
    rightarg = text,
    procedure = public.contains
);
```

but got error

```
ERROR:  column "searchin" does not exist
LINE 5: SELECT position( searchFor in searchIn )<>0;
```

How to make it work in 9.1 ? In 9.3 it works.

Using

"PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL already defines an `@@` operator on `(text,text)` in the `pg_catalog` schema, which is defined as:

```
regress=> \do @@
                                  List of operators
   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |    Description    
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------
 pg_catalog | @@   | text          | text           | boolean     | text search match
```

That is taking precedence over the `@@` you defined in the `public` schema.

I suggest using the operator `<@` for `contains`, because [that's consistent with the array contains and contained-by operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html). There's no usage of it in `pg_catalog` for `text` ... but there's no guarantee one won't be added in a future version or by an extension.

If you want to guarantee that your operators take precedence over those in `pg_catalog`, you need to put them in a different schema and put it first on the search path, explicitly before `pg_catalog`. So something like:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_operators;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_operators.contains(searchFor text, searchIn text)
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
AS $BODY$
SELECT position( searchFor in searchIn)<>0;
$BODY$;

CREATE OPERATOR my_operators.<@ (
    leftarg = text,
    rightarg = text,
    procedure = public.contains
);
```

then

```
SET search_path = 'my_operators, pg_catalog, public';
```

which you can do with `ALTER USER` and/or `ALTER DATABASE` to make it a default.

Comment: Answer does not contain `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` . Should it added to help planner? Is it reasonable and possible to add `COMMUTATOR, RESTRICT, JOIN, HASHES, MERGES` clauses ? Is it better to use language sql instead of pgsql ?

Comment: @Andrus Actually `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` and `STRICT` can inhibit inlining, and are better omitted if possible. The documentation needs to be clearer about that. Yes, it's quite reasonable to add a commutator `@>` operator. I don't see how you'd implement hashing.

Comment: How to create operator only if it does not exist ? I tried `CREATE OPERATOR IF NOT EXISTS public.<@` but got error

Comment: @Andrus Use a `DO` block that looks it up in `pg_operator`, I guess. Not every statement type has `IF NOT EXISTS`. Personally I strongly suggest packaging it in an *extension* instead. The documentation covers the creation of extensions. You don't need any C code for an extension, it can be just an SQL file, Makefile and extension control file.

Comment: In 9.1 code from your answer causes error. I updated question. How to make it work in 9.1 also ?

Comment: @Andrus replace searchfor with $1 and searcin with $2